# Newtson.Json FileLoadException only on CI server

Tags: .net, json.net, nunit, teamcity

TeamCity 9 and NUnit 2.6.4 is having a problem running tests, it all works fine locally. The issue seems to be with a reference to Newtonsoft.Json (as usual).

```
Test(s) failed. System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes)
   at MyCompany.Testing.WebAPI.ControllerTestAssistant.PrepareActionContext(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpController controller) 
   at MyCompany.Web.Http.HttpResponseBuilderTests.PrepareActionContext(HttpRequestMessage request) 
   at MyCompany.Web.Http.HttpResponseBuilderTests.PrepareBuilder(String url) 
   at MyCompany.Web.Http.HttpResponseBuilderTests.HttpResponseBuilder_BuildResponse__when__success_get_with_no_rowversion__then__200OK_with_no_etag()
```

The solution is huge. I've updated all Json.NET package to 7.x and I've checked all binding references in all config files.

Everything is good locally on all team's dev PCs. It's a problem only on the build server, under the NUnit runner.

I think `System.Net.Http.Formatting` has a hard reference on version 6.x. It's as if the test runner isn't heeding the binding redirects in config.

I'm going to start weening myself off Json.NET, its becoming more trouble than its worth, and it doesn't help that VS provides no help for solving such problems.

Thanks for any help.

Luke

---

Fusion log shows that the assembly binding redirect is not being seen, even though its there. Colleagues have sanity checked.

It's weird.

Have removed all other redirects in the `app.config` for the test project and trying with just the Json.NET redirect.

---

> No application configuration file found

In Fusion log, getting closer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I had a reference to another test DLL, so the bin folder ended up with two `*Tests.DLL` files in it.

TeamCity was configured by wildcard and then ran tests in both. The referenced DLL had no config file and could not load the right version of Json.NET

The tests in the referenced DLL had already been ran and passed. I referenced another test lib in order to get at some helper setup code!

Normally, I configure TeamCity to run tests on explicit DLL paths.